# XPATH Help to select multiple instances of the same elements

Tags: xml, xpath

I am using a tool that allows for Xpath expressions to fetch information for presentation and selection... Given the xml *(below)* file for intput, I am trying to determine an Xpath to select and return multiple artists based on on title and country previously selected

So I fetch country:

```
 ROW:   //CATALOG/CD/COUNTRY[not(. = ../following-sibling;;CD/COUNTRY)]
 COLUMN: ----
```

then I fetch title:

```
 ROW:   //CATALOG/CD[contains(./COUNTRY,'${cdcountry.value}')]
 COLUMN:  ./TITLE
```

and I fetch artists:

```
  ROW:  //CATALOG/CD[contains(./TITLE,'${cdtitle.value}')]
  COLUMN: ./ARTIST
```

**XML FILE**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CATALOG>
    <CD>
        <TITLE>Title1</TITLE>
        <ARTIST>Beatles</ARTIST>
        <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
        <COMPANY>Columbia</COMPANY>
        <PRICE>10.90</PRICE>
        <YEAR>1985</YEAR>
    </CD>
    <CD>
        <TITLE>Title2</TITLE>
        <ARTIST>Bonnie Tyler</ARTIST>
        <ARTIST>Taylor Swift</ARTIST>
        <ARTIST>Beastie Boys</ARTIST>
        <COUNTRY>US</COUNTRY>
        <COMPANY>CBS Records</COMPANY>
        <PRICE>9.90</PRICE>
        <YEAR>1988</YEAR>
    </CD>
    <CD>
        <TITLE>Title3</TITLE>
        <ARTIST>Eros Ramazzotti</ARTIST>
        <COUNTRY>IT</COUNTRY>
        <COMPANY>BMG</COMPANY>
        <PRICE>9.90</PRICE>
        <YEAR>1997</YEAR>
    </CD>
</CATALOG>
```

Comment: What is the question exactly? Any problem with those XPath expressions you posted?

Comment: I cant seem to grab multiple Artists...so I can grab artists(once)say company price  or year... yet I have the need to be able to return [for example for Title2 all the artists(3)

Comment: Basic XPath to do that is : `//CATALOG/CD[TITLE='Title2']/ARTIST`. If that doesn't return multiple `ARTIST` for you, then there is a problem somewhere else (not in the XPath part)